# How to make the app install another app inside them and execute the new installed app in IOS

Tags: ios, core-animation, in-app-purchase

I need to use the in app purchase server model, where I want the user to buy the the new interactive storybooks for kids and play the book.

I have searched through the net, but was off the luck.

just like -- http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/playtales-kids-interactive/id389523239?mt=8

How to get this work. please help

Thanks a ton.

Comment: i found the same question but no answer for it -- [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836409/in-app-purchase-server-product-model-am-i-doing-it-right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "install another app" programmatically. What you can do is to open the URL of your second app in iTunes from your application with `UIApplication openURL`. When you invoke this method with a link in iTunes, the App Store application will automatically open with the information page of your second application. Here the user can purchase it with a simple click.

On the other hand, the link you posted above does not use this approach but downloads/enables some new feature (a new e-book) in the application that was hidden before. I.e. all books were already in the application at the time of download, only they were hidden, or it downloads them from a server via a custom protocol defined by the application.

Comment: That is what i want to know , how the new feature downloaded is executed ?

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial: http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/

In `- (void)provideContent:(NSString *)productId` you can download the eBook in your format from some secret / authenticated URL, or if you have shipped it in the application bundle, you can make it visible (perhaps this is the simpler way)

Comment: MrTJ thanks for the in app purchase , but My question is regarding the product purchased, just think this way - I have a application with the animation story book which have a menu page with one free book and some new books will get downloaded on purchase. i want want these books to be download from the server and user can read this inside the main application. This is what is being done by the [App] (http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/playtales-kids-interactive/id389523239?mt=8).

Comment: What you say is about the ebook i.e pdf format , i can download it from the server link and save it to Library or Document Folder , and make them read by the user but my question is about adding new feature to App.

Comment: You can pack your books into a single ZIP or any other format of your preference and download it with with `NSUrlRequest`. To prevent that everybody could download it you should add the `transactionReceipt` of the purchase of the user (for example as a custom header in the url request) and then the server can validate the receipt with Apple. All this is described very well here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html especially the "Verifying store receipts" part.

Comment: You can download the pdf to the private folder of your application so nobody else can see / stole it but your app.